# CCSM isn't remembering my settings.

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

I am currently using Gnome Shell on Precise and trying to disable the <kbd><Alt>Button1</kbd> shortcut for dragging windows. I have taken the following steps.

1. Pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, typed `ccsm` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Scrolled down to "Move Window" and clicked it.

   [image]
3. Clicked the <kbd><Alt>Button1</kbd> button next to "Initiate Window Move".

   [image]
4. Unchecked the "Enabled" box and clicked <kbd>OK</kbd>.

   [image]
5. Closed `ccsm` and restarted it.

Sadly, as soon as I restart `ccsm`, it appears that nothing has actually been modified since "Initiate Window Move" still seems to be mapped to <kbd><Alt>Button1</kbd>. No matter how many times I perform the above steps and restart `ccsm`, I still get the same results.

What do I need to do to disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

1. Start CCSM.
2. In the left pane, click "**Preferences**".
3. In the right pane, under "**Integration**", deselect "**Enable integration into the desktop environment**".

I have no idea what that option does, but after a lot of trial-and-error, I found that worked for me.  After that, I was able to get my "**Move Windows**" settings to stick.

Comment: I checked and that option was already enabled. I still have the same problem.

Comment: The "Enable integration into the desktop environment" needs to be "DISABLED".  Are you sure you DISABLED it?

Comment: This works, but results in some of my other settings no longer working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using Gnome Shell and Gnome Shell does not run on Compiz, but on Mutter.

To fix this issue, you need to change the modifier key that is used for moving windows in your keyboard settings:
[image]

Comment: I tried disabling the one you highlighted but it didn't work. I can still drag windows by holding down [Alt] and dragging them.